# Calculate average for each day and store in array for provided timeframe

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have an array of object:

```
let bookDetails = [{'bookName':'harrypottar','readingTime':1231,"date":"2021-04-19 07:07:58.896Z"}, 
                   {'bookName':'lotr','readingTime':909,"date":"2021-04-19 07:07:58.896Z"},
                   {'bookName':'harrypottar','readingTime':190,"date":"2021-04-20 07:07:58.896Z"},
                   {'bookName':'lotr','readingTime':1254,"date":"2021-04-21 07:07:58.896Z"},  
                   {'bookName':'lotr','readingTime':10,"date":"2021-04-21 07:07:58.896Z"}]
```

I want to calculate average readingTime for each day in an array of 30 days.

I want to calculate readingTime average of each day and store in an array representing 30 days of month.  **Expected O/P** : **[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1070,190,632,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]**

For this I tried :,

to calculate count for each day we can use below method:

```
let bookReadEveryDay = Array(30).fill(0);
bookDetails.forEach((obj) => {
    const day = new Date(obj.date).getDate();
    ++bookReadEveryDay[day];
}
bookReadEveryDay = bookReadEveryDay.map(function (x) { return x  })
```

console.log(invoiceEveryDay) => **[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]** => It gives count for each day in an array. i.e. for 19th there are 2 elements, for 20th there is 1 element and for 21st day there are 2 elements, but rest since there are no other days , hence it is 0.

But instead of having count I want to calculate average readingTime for each day. If anyone got any idea or needs any more information please let me know.

Comment: Can you add the expected results it will help a bit .

Comment: I have included expected O/P. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could collect time and ccount and render the average time for each day.

```js
const
    bookDetails = [{ bookName: 'harrypottar', readingTime: 1231, date: "2021-04-19 07:07:58.896Z"}, { bookName: 'lotr', readingTime: 909, date: "2021-04-19 07:07:58.896Z" }, { bookName: 'harrypottar', readingTime: 190, date: "2021-04-20 07:07:58.896Z" }, { bookName: 'lotr', readingTime: 1254, date: "2021-04-21 07:07:58.896Z" }, { bookName: 'lotr', readingTime: 10, date: "2021-04-21 07:07:58.896Z" }],
    temp = bookDetails.reduce((r, { readingTime, date }) => {
        const key = +date.slice(8, 10);
        r[key] = r[key] || { count: 0, time: 0 };
        r[key].time += readingTime;
        r[key].count++;
        return r;
    }, {}),
    result = Array.from({ length: 30 }, (_, i) => temp[i + 1]
        ? temp[i + 1].time / temp[i + 1].count
        : 0
    );

console.log(...result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution, could you please tell me why you did, 

const key = +date.slice(8, 10);

Comment: Could you please give ma a brief on the code? That would be really helpful

Answer (score 2):

```
let bookDetails = [
      { bookName: 'harrypottar', readingTime: 1231, date: '2021-04-19 07:07:58.896Z' },
      { bookName: 'lotr', readingTime: 909, date: '2021-04-19 07:07:58.896Z' },
      { bookName: 'harrypottar', readingTime: 190, date: '2021-04-20 07:07:58.896Z' },
      { bookName: 'lotr', readingTime: 1254, date: '2021-04-21 07:07:58.896Z' },
      { bookName: 'lotr', readingTime: 10, date: '2021-04-21 07:07:58.896Z' },
];

const result = bookDetails.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const day = new Date(item.date).getDate();
   acc[day] = acc.hasOwnProperty(day) ? 
              { readerCount: acc[day].readerCount + 1, readingTime: 
               acc[day].readingTime + item.readingTime }
             : { readerCount: 1, readingTime: item.readingTime };
    return acc;
 }, {});

for (var i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
  result[i] = (result[i] && result[i].readingTime / result[i].readerCount) || 0;
}

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Note: The above code will always have 31 entries irrespective of month need to handle that dynamically if needed based on the month.

Comment: This looks more understandable for me but my expected O/P is in array. Could you please provide O/P in simple array not as object.

Comment: @SivaPradhan you can do Object.values(result)